# C2471: cannot update program database

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I am using MSBuild.exe 12.0 (visual studio 2013) to build c++ projects on MS 2022 server.
I got build error **C2471: cannot update program database**
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Compiler Error C2471](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2471?view=msvc-170) doc?

Comment: Related issue for Visual Studio 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286191/visual-studio-2015-cannot-update-program-database-error-c2471

Answer (score 1):

If you have KB5029365 installed, try removing it.

I experienced the same problem after installing the update, and removing the update solved my problem.